# Excel remove rows that have certain words in a column

Tags: vba, excel

I am new to excel scripting/macroing

I have a massive excel sheet and I need to remove some rows from it.

Any rows that have the words: cat, dog, horse, fish

Have tried something like this (as well as quite a few other atempts).

```
Sub DeleteRows() 
    Dim c As Range 
    Dim SrchRng 

    Set SrchRng = ActiveSheet.Range("A1", ActiveSheet.Range("A65536").End(xlUp)) 
    Do 
        Set c = SrchRng.Find("dog","cat","horse","fish", LookIn:=xlValues) 
        If Not c Is Nothing Then c.EntireRow.Delete 
    Loop While Not c Is Nothing 
End Sub
```

Some details (since I am unsure what information is truely needed).

These words would always be in the 2nd column (but it could be something like "The George fish" and it would need to remove that row.

Any help would be great, thanks!

Comment: You need to add `LookAt:=xlPart` so that it finds partial matches.

Answer (score 0):

I have accomplished this without the help of Macros or scripts.

In the Data tab select filter, then select filter by word containing.

Enter the words, then simply delete all the rows that appear.

Answering incase anyone else has this problem in the future!

Answer (score 0):

This works.

```
Sub DeleteRows()

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim lastRow As Long
Dim lookAt As Range, thisCell As Range, nextCell As Range
Dim keyWord(0 To 3) As String, targetColumn As String
Dim i As Integer

keyWord(0) = "cat"
keyWord(1) = "dog"
keyWord(2) = "horse"
keyWord(3) = "fish"

On Error GoTo Err

Set ws = Application.ActiveSheet

'get last populated row number
With ws
    If WorksheetFunction.CountA(Cells) > 0 Then
        lastRow = Cells.Find(what:="*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
    End If
End With

'define the target column
targetColumn = "A"
Set lookAt = ActiveSheet.Range(targetColumn & "1:" & targetColumn & lastRow)

'for each item in keyWord array
For i = LBound(keyWord) To UBound(keyWord)
    'look for that word throughout range
    Set thisCell = lookAt.Find(what:=keyWord(i), LookIn:=xlValues, lookAt:=xlPart, SearchDirection:=xlNext)
        If Not thisCell Is Nothing Then
            Set nextCell = thisCell
            Do
                Set thisCell = lookAt.FindNext(After:=thisCell)
                If Not thisCell Is Nothing Then
                    If InStr(1, thisCell.Text, keyWord(i)) Then
                        thisCell.ClearContents
                    End If
                Else
                    Exit Do
                End If
            Loop
        End If
Next i

' delete empty rows
On Error Resume Next
    Range(targetColumn & "1:" & targetColumn & lastRow).Select
    Selection.EntireRow.SpecialCells(xlBlanks).EntireRow.Delete

Err:
    Exit Sub

End Sub
```